# Why i cannot make my side-navbar to appear and disappear

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please forgive me but i'll paste all my code here so that someone can spot the error. I have tried it for the last couple of days with no Success. Just want my navbar to appear and disappear on click. Thats it,THANKS in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Nav Bar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <style>
     @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700");
    </style>
</head>
<body>   
    <nav class="menu">
    <header>Menu <span>×</span></header>
    <ol>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">About</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#0">Widgets</a>
            <ol class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Grocerry</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Discount</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Huge Sale</a></li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#0">Juice</a>
            <ol class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Russi</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Paneer Pyaza</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Rasbhari</a></li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Contact</a></li>
    </ol>
    <footer><button aria-label="Toggle Menu">Toggle</button></footer>
</nav> 
<script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

   var $els = $('.menu a, .menu header');
var count = $els.length;
var grouplength = Math.ceil(count/3);
var groupNumber = 0;
var i = 1;
$('.menu').css('--count',count+'');
$els.each(function(j){
    if ( i > grouplength ) {
        groupNumber++;
        i=1;
    }
    $(this).attr('data-group',groupNumber);
    i++;
});

$('.menu footer button').on('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $els.each(function(j){
        $(this).css('--top',$(this)[0].getBoundingClientRect().top + ($(this).attr('data-group') * -15) - 20);
        $(this).css('--delay-in',j*.1+'s');
        $(this).css('--delay-out',(count-j)*.1+'s');
    });
    $('.menu').toggleClass('closed');
    e.stopPropagation();
});

// run animation once at beginning for demo
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.menu footer button').click();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.menu footer button').click();
    }, (count * 100) + 500 );
}, 1000);    
</script>
</body>
</html>


* {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }
  body {
    margin: 0;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  nav {
    --duration: .5s;
    --easing: ease-in-out;
    position: relative;
    width: 220px;
    margin: 20px;
  }
  nav ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  nav li {
    margin: -4px 0 0 0;
  }
  nav a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #fff;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transition: transform var(--duration) var(--easing), color var(--duration) var(--easing);
    transition-delay: var(--delay-out);
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 1em 1.52em;
  }
  nav a:hover {
    background: #efefef;
  }
  nav .sub-menu a {
    font-size: .9em;
    color: #666666;
    border-left: 2em solid white;
    padding: .75em;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #dddddd 2px, #ffffff 2px);
  }
  nav .sub-menu a:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #dddddd 2px, #efefef 2px);
  }
  nav header {
    font-weight: 600;
    display: block;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transition: transform var(--duration) var(--easing), color var(--duration) var(--easing);
    transition-delay: var(--delay-out);
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 1em 1.52em;
  }
  nav header span {
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 1;
    float: right;
  }
  nav footer button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: none;
    padding: calc(1em - 2px);
    width: 100%;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transition: transform var(--duration) var(--easing);
    transition-delay: calc(var(--duration) + (.1s * (var(--count) / 2)));
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    background: #cdcdcd;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  nav.closed a,
  nav.closed header {
    transform: translateY(calc(var(--top) * -1)) scaleY(0.1) scaleX(0.2);
    transition-delay: var(--delay-in);
    color: transparent;
  }
  nav.closed footer button {
    transition-delay: 0s;
    transform: scaleY(0.7) scaleX(0.2);
  }
```

any assistance will be appreciated. i want my side-navbar to appear and disappear on click.

Comment: I am sorry i did not put some background colour in my css, but when you add some colour you will notice that when you click on menu the menu items disappear but there is a block of white side-navbar that remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, try the following code to add fading effect. Here, I have used fadetoggle() instead of toggle()

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Nav Bar</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".toggle").click(function(){
    $(".nav").fadeToggle(1000);
 
  });
    
});
</script>
<style>
* {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }
  body {
    margin: 0;
    background-size: cover;
  }
 nav {
  /*   --duration: .5s;
    --easing: ease-in-out;*/
    position: relative;
    width: 220px;
    margin: 20px;
  }
  nav ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  nav li {
    margin: -4px 0 0 0;
  }
  nav a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #fff;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
  /* transition: transform var(--duration) var(--easing), color var(--duration) var(--easing);
    transition-delay: var(--delay-out);*/
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 1em 1.52em;
  }
  nav a:hover {
    background: #efefef;
  }
  nav .sub-menu a {
    font-size: .9em;
    color: #666666;
    border-left: 2em solid white;
    padding: .75em;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #dddddd 2px, #ffffff 2px);
  }
  nav .sub-menu a:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #dddddd 2px, #efefef 2px);
  }
 h1.toggle {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 0px solid #e8e8e8;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width:15.5%
}

h1.toggle:hover {
    background: #e8e8e8;
}

h1 span {
    float: right;
    font-size: 27px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -9px;
}

</style>
 </head>
<body>   
<h1 class="toggle">Menu <span>×</span></h1>
    <nav class="nav">
 
    <ol>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">About</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#0">Widgets</a>
            <ol class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Grocerry</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Discount</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Huge Sale</a></li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#0">Juice</a>
            <ol class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Russi</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Paneer Pyaza</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Rasbhari</a></li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Contact</a></li>
    </ol>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are the best man. Thanks so much. Hope you do not mind if i come back and ask other questions. Cheers!!!

Comment: Thanks for the compliment...Sure you can ask any further queries you have.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem in your HTML structure. I have edited your code a bit to make it work. Also, I have used a script for jquery. Hope it will help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Nav Bar</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".toggle").click(function(){
    $(".nav").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
<style>
* {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.5;
  }
  body {
    margin: 0;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  nav {
    --duration: .5s;
    --easing: ease-in-out;
    position: relative;
    width: 220px;
    margin: 20px;
  }
  nav ol {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  nav li {
    margin: -4px 0 0 0;
  }
  nav a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    background: #fff;
    transform-origin: 0 0;
    transition: transform var(--duration) var(--easing), color var(--duration) var(--easing);
    transition-delay: var(--delay-out);
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 1em 1.52em;
  }
  nav a:hover {
    background: #efefef;
  }
  nav .sub-menu a {
    font-size: .9em;
    color: #666666;
    border-left: 2em solid white;
    padding: .75em;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #dddddd 2px, #ffffff 2px);
  }
  nav .sub-menu a:hover {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #dddddd 2px, #efefef 2px);
  }
 h1.toggle {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 0px solid #e8e8e8;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width:15.5%
}

h1.toggle:hover {
    background: #e8e8e8;
}

h1 span {
    float: right;
    font-size: 27px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -9px;
}
</style>
 </head>
<body>   
<h1 class="toggle">Menu <span>×</span></h1>
    <nav class="nav">
 
    <ol>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">About</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#0">Widgets</a>
            <ol class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Grocerry</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Discount</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Huge Sale</a></li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <a href="#0">Juice</a>
            <ol class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Russi</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Paneer Pyaza</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Rasbhari</a></li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#0">Contact</a></li>
    </ol>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, the problem with the code is that by using it my navbar looses the stylish ease in and ease out delay transition. If i can maintain the initial style and still be able to achieve the function you have created i'd be happy. Thanks for the effort.